# Which if statement to use to make sure facebook is referrer??

Tags: facebook, if-statement

Which php if statement should i use to tell a user the file on my server can only be visited from facebook

At the moment i only read out the fuid and the app settings. But i like to prevent the file to be use as a page behind my domain.

What is the proper way to do this?
should i use something like

```
if( $_SERVER['referrer'] != facebook.com ){
echo "This page should be visited from facebook";
}
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I'm posting to let you know that the referrer can be forged so you shouldn't base any real security on this.

Comment: Would you be willing for have a facebook app to be the "gate" to your content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the referrer but as mah said it can be forged. If you are not too concerned about it use that method.

If you are actually creating a Facebook App and it is a page that is loaded in a canvas on Facebook you can check for a valid signed_request.